# Foreground Service crashing on Android 14

Tags: android, service, foreground-service, android-14

I have an Android application that worked fine until Android 13. After upgrading to Android 14 (Setting targetSdkVersion as 34) my application is Crashing on Android 14. Here's my crash log.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.bleapp.service.BleAppService@1d05078 with Intent { cmp=com.example.bleapp/.service.BleAppService }: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type connectedDevice callerApp=ProcessRecord{718b5ad 5016:com.example.bleapp/u0a356} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, android.permission.NFC, android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR, android.permission.UWB_RANGING, USB Device, USB Accessory]
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4839)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type connectedDevice callerApp=ProcessRecord{718b5ad 5016:com.example.bleapp/u0a356} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CONNECTED_DEVICE] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE, android.permission.NFC, android.permission.TRANSMIT_IR, android.permission.UWB_RANGING, USB Device, USB Accessory]
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3057)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:3041)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:3024)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2966)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6761)
  at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:775)
  at com.example.bleapp.service.BleAppService.onStartCommand(BleAppService.kt:28)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:4821)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleServiceArgs(Unknown Source:0)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2289)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
```

Comment: It comes with another issue. See this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76949759/foregroundservicetype-0x00000001-is-not-a-subset-of-foregroundservicetype-attrib)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Starting from Android 14, you need to declare a specific permission for foreground service, depending on the use case you are using Foreground service for. This is a normal level permission and can be granted by simply declaring it in manifest. A list of supported permissions along with uses cases can be found here.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#use-cases

Example:

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
  <application ...>
  <service
      android:name=".MyService"
      android:foregroundServiceType="location"
      android:exported="false">
  </service>
</application>
```

You also need to add the proper foreground service call at runtime:

`Service.startForeground(0, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)`

Comment: Something is slightly misleading in the way Google communicates about API34 changes : these constraints not only apply to _Services_ but also to _Workers_, if they call `setForegroundAsync`.

In that case, the manifest has to be updated too, by declaring `android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"`


Reference : https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running#foreground-service-type

Comment: This does not imply that you do not need to request the normal runtime location permission anymore. 
You still need to set it up and request it in the same way as before since runtime permissions were added.

Comment: @Ajith M A It not fix the issue, my app still crash on Android 14 after following Google guide line.

Comment: @DzungPV Were you able to fix it? What was the issue?

Comment: @AjithMA it still crash on Samsung, I still not found any solution.

Comment: I found a solution where you first have to check if the coarse and fine location are granted before starting foregroundService. It worker for me and is a nice solution.

Comment: What's this? "You also need to add the proper foreground service call at runtime:

Service.startForeground(0, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)"?

I use this to run the service: 
Intent(this, LocationService::class.java).also { intent ->
            bindService(intent, connection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }

Answer (score 4):

I solved this problem with my location service. Please note this:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#fgs-prerequisites

> Beginning with Android 14 (API level 34), when you launch a foreground service, the system checks for specific prerequisites based on service type. For example, if you try to launch a foreground service of type location, the system checks to make sure your app already has either the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. If it doesn't, the system throws `SecurityException`. 
> For this reason, you must confirm that the required prerequisites are met **before you start a foreground service**. The foreground service type documentation lists the required prerequisites for each foreground service type.

I added a check to the code to check the granted permissions before starting the service and the application no longer crashes.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
  && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
)
{
  val intent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
  context.startForegroundService(intent)
} else {
  Log.e("MyService", "No permissions ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION!")
}
```

My manifest file:

```
<manifest ...>
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
  <!-- permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION"/>
  
  <application ...>
    <service
      android:name=".MyService"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:exported="false"
      android:foregroundServiceType="location"
      android:stopWithTask="false"
    />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: why declaring  != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED  ,
this canbe misleading ,
shouldn't be like this ? : 
== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

Comment: @joghm Yes you are right. I fixed the error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

In my App, this code was the problem. In Noftication from work manager. I removed this.

```
 setForegroundAsync(ForegroundInfo(notificationId, builder.build()))
```

The error would also occurrs because of the wrong notificationID.