# foregroundServiceType 0x00000001 is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000000 in service element of manifest file

Tags: android-workmanager, foreground-service, android-14

I have implemented Foreground Service using WorkManager, it works fine upto API Level 33. Since it is mandatory in API Level 34 to specify foregroundServiceType, I specified it in Worker and in the Manifest but getting this error.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Required Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

<service
        android:name=".services.DownloadService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="true"
        tools:node="merge"
        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"/>
```

**Inside Worker:**

```
 setForegroundAsync(
       ForegroundInfo(
            NOTIFICATION_ID,
            getNotification(),
            ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_DATA_SYNC
       )
  )
```

**Getting this error**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foregroundServiceType 0x00000001
> is not a subset of foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000000 in
> service element of manifest file                                  at
> android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3015)
> at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978)
> at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920)
> at
> android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.setServiceForeground(IActivityManager.java:6079)
> at android.app.Service.startForeground(Service.java:797) ...

I tried making some changes here and there but nothing works.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to @sebastian I got the right answer for this exception, when no services are used in application, but WorkManager is used.
The full answer would be to add into `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<service
        android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
        tools:node="merge" />
```

Also add proper permission in the same file, based on `foregroundServiceType` that is defined for that service. In this case, add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_DATA_SYNC"/>
```

And to call `startForegroundAsync`, create ForegroundInfo on the following way:

```
ForegroundInfo foregroundInfo;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    foregroundInfo = new ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_DATA_SYNC);
} else {
    foregroundInfo = new ForegroundInfo(notificationId, notification);
}
setForegroundAsync(foregroundInfo);
```

Answer (score 9):

Try adding

```
<service
  android:name="androidx.work.impl.foreground.SystemForegroundService"
  android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync"
  tools:node="merge" />
```

to the Manifest.

Source: [Documenation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running#declare-foreground-service-types-manifest)

Answer (score 1):

Error message says that foregroundServiceType you have used to invoke your service isn't declared in Manifest. It seems like you have declared your service type as "mediaPlayback" in manifest and is trying to launch it as "dataSync". You can also define multiple foregroundServiceTypes for your service and use one of them while launching service depending upon use case you are starting service. To provide multiple types in declaration, you may separate all your types by a pipe(|) symbol. Try changing your code as below or remove mediaPlayback if its not required.

```
<service
    android:name=".services.DownloadService"
    android:exported="false"
    android:enabled="true"
    tools:node="merge"
    android:foregroundServiceType="dataSync|mediaPlayback"/>
```

Reference: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required

Comment: Yes you are right but I was just testing out with different foregroundServiceType, still you can see in the error 'foregroundServiceType attribute 0x00000000'. The attribute value doesn't change whether it is dataSync or any other value.

Comment: Can you try without passing the type parameter when you start the service? I am using below inside my service onStartCommand ->        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_SERVICE, getForegroundNotification(this))

Comment: Yes I tried that. I am using WorkManager, so I tried this way 
doWork() -> setForegroundAsync( ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification())).

It didn't work and getting this erro:
android.app.InvalidForegroundServiceTypeException: Starting FGS with type none callerApp=ProcessRecord{1e7c68f 6604:com.inFamous.status_saver/u0a185} targetSDK=34 has been prohibited

Comment: I get precisely the same issue as OP, for the same reason and following the same journey. I remember testing Android 14 as a target, using a Worker without specifying the foreground service type, and it was working fine with a previous Android 14 version (beta 1 or 2, can't remember), but this `Starting FGS with type none` issue started appearing with a more recent beta. By the way, the sample code at https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/how-to/long-running does not provide a type.