# Starting TGS with type location ... TargetSDK=34 - Android 14 Crash on Startup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions, foreground-service

I updated to Android 14 last night. Once I attempted to install our app (from Play Store) on my device I started getting a crash upon opening the app

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.appname, PID: 1518
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.myapp.StartupService: 
java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type location callerApp=ProcessRecord{95e97ef 
1518:com.myapp.appname/u0a370} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true 
[android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions allOf=false 
[android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION] and the app 
must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4664)
```

I've tried adding some of the newly required permissions into my manifest.  When everything was tested on the beta it worked fine (as far as I know).

I've also tried the solutions shown in [this question: Foreground Service crashing on Android 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943771/foreground-service-crashing-on-android-14), which seems very similar.

Here are my files. I tried to include what I thought was necessary. Let me know if there are pieces that help provide more context.

### Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...

    <application
        android:name=".BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:resizeableActivity="false"
        android:theme="@style/appTheme"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <activity
            ...

        <!-- Service used when app is initializing on start up -->
        <service android:name="com.myapp.StartupService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:exported="false"
            >
        </service>
            ...
        <service
            android:name="com.myapp.chat.push.FcmListenerService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
            ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

### Startup Service

```
class StartupService : IntentService {
    constructor() : super("StartupService") {}
    constructor(name: String?) : super(name) {}

    private val STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID = 42
    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        val name: CharSequence = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name_misc)
        val description = getString(R.string.notification_channel_description_misc)
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
            AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_MISCELLANEOUS,
            name,
            importance
        )
        channel.description = description
        channel.setSound(null, null)
        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(
            NotificationManager::class.java
        )
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    @Deprecated("Deprecated in Java")
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        createNotificationChannel()
        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
            applicationContext,
            AppConstants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_MISCELLANEOUS
        )
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notification_startup_title))
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notification_startup_text))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_small)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
        startForeground(STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build()) // THIS LINE IS THROWING THE ERROR
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how about Kotlin, but in Java, from SDK 34 (apart from permissions and typeService parameter for service in Manifest, which you defined have correct) you must add an extra parameter - service type, as 3rd parameter - when you start the service:

```
startForeground(STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build(), FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)
```

Where FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION is constant from ServiceInfo.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Exception I can see that issue(targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true) is on permissions. you should provide all the permission of `FOREGROUND_SERVICE`. To correct it please follow below details.

**Request the foreground service permissions**

Apps that target Android 9 (API level 28) or higher and use foreground services need to request the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` in the app manifest, as shown in the following code snippet. This is a normal permission, so the system automatically grants it to the requesting app.

In addition, if the app targets API level 34 or higher, it must request the appropriate permission type for the kind of work the foreground service will be doing. Each foreground service type has a corresponding permission type. For example, if an app launches a foreground service that uses the camera, you must request both the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` and `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA` permissions. These are all normal permissions, so the system grants them automatically if they're listed in the manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA"/>

    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note:** If an app that targets API level 28 or higher attempts to create a foreground service without requesting the `FOREGROUND_SERVICE` permission, the system throws a SecurityException. Similarly, if an app targets API level 34 or higher and doesn't request the appropriate specific permission, the system throws SecurityException.

**Reference:** [Click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#types)

Comment: I have read through all of that. I have the necessary permissions from what I can tell. Since I'm requesting location permissions I have FOREGROUND_SERVICE, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION. From the docs, I think I have everything I am supposed to have: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required?authuser=1#location

Comment: You should provide this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_CAMERA"/>

Comment: I didn't show it in my example, but that permission is in there

Comment: Answer is totally depend on the facts and data You have provided, It's good permission was there.

Comment: have you read this article to request the permissions?  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#fgs-prerequisites

Don't forget to declare the service Type in for ground service.     https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fg-service-types

Comment: one more discrepancy I have found, in manifest i have found android:foregroundServiceType="location" but in StartupService you are starting the service with 'startForeground(STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())' whereas this should be start with FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION, for more reference follow this https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fg-service-types#location

Answer (score 0):

You might have to move the line which is throwing error:

```
startForeground(STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build())
```

into `onStartCommand`. Thus:

```
private lateinit var notification: Notification

override fun onCreate() {

    notification = Notification.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                ...
                .build()

}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    startForeground(STARTUP_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
}
```

[Google's document](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#start) says:

> Inside the service, usually in `onStartCommand()`, you can request
> that your service run in the foreground. To do so, call
> `ServiceCompat.startForeground()`

I think it is needed that the service itself has already been started to start another foreground service for its notification.

Answer (score 0):

> The system checks for proper use of foreground service types and
> confirms that the app has requested the proper runtime permissions or
> uses the required APIs. For instance, the system expects apps that use
> the foreground service type FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION type to
> request either ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.
>
> This implies that apps must follow a very specific order of operations
> when requesting permissions from the user and starting foreground
> services. Permissions must be requested and granted before the app
> attempts to call startForeground(). Apps that request the appropriate
> permissions after the foreground service has been started must change
> this order of operations and request the permission before starting
> the foreground service.

As written in the documentation, before you start or invoke any Service, you must check if the required permissions in your case `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` are granted at runtime and if not, you must request those permissions and grant them, before starting the service.

Comment: Does that mean I would have to prompt the user for these permissions at run time?

Comment: I guess I don't understand what this looks like.

Comment: Yes, you need to prompt the user as mentioned in this guide for those permissions before starting your service https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: But that's not at runtime. That's the confusing part. "Ask for a permission in context, when the user starts to interact with the feature that requires it." My app doesn't need permissions at runtime. It needs the location after logging in.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION" />
```

And

```
 <service
            android:name=".floatingview.FloatingViewService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location"
            android:exported="false" />
```

This is how I was able to fix this problem.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" android:foregroundServiceType="location" />

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77642329/8313316

> Beginning with Android 14 (API level 34), when you launch a foreground service, the system checks for specific prerequisites based on service type. For example, if you try to launch a foreground service of type location, the system checks to make sure your app already has either the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission. If it doesn't, the system throws `SecurityException`. 
> For this reason, you must confirm that the required prerequisites are met **before you start a foreground service**. The foreground service type documentation lists the required prerequisites for each foreground service type.

Answer (score 0):

here is the complete demo how to do it when dealing with location with boot compatible forground service if you don't wan't to start service after the device restart then you could exclude code for

> ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

from the demo app

https://github.com/JigarRangani/ForGroundLocation

Answer (score -1):

solved by adding below 2 lines in  manifest file:

1. adding this:

.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
```

2. adding this line to service:

   android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"