# Android 14 startForeground on BOOT_COMPLETED SecurityException

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to migrate to Android 14 and my app has a feature which will keep running as a foreground service even if you reboot your device (it is a tool, so this functionality is needed), the app displays a notification to the user (with a Stop button). To start the service, the user needs to click on a button in the app, but now after I changed compileSdk to 34 from 33 I get an error when I try to call `startForeground(1, notification, FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_LOCATION)` in the service `onCreate` on `BOOT_COMPLETED` BroadcastReceiver:

```
Unable to create service MainService: java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type location callerApp=ProcessRecord{ef58f87 3065:com.xxx/u0a196} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION] any of the permissions allOf=false [android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION]  and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission
```

I have added everything needed in the manifest file including the `android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION` permission and declaring `android:foregroundServiceType="location"` for the service.

Does anyone know what am I missing? Do I need to request `FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION` permission at runtime? I am already requesting `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission at runtime.

Thanks!

Comment: have you check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943771/foreground-service-crashing-on-android-14

Comment: here is the complete demo how to do it when dealing with location with boot compatible forground service if you don't wan't to start service after the device restart then you could exclude code for

    ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

from the demo app

https://github.com/JigarRangani/ForGroundLocation

Comment: It just needed ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission, works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It just needed `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission, works fine now. Thanks to Jigar Rangani!